# Glassfish / Payara deployment failure CDI deployment failure:javax/faces/component/behavior/ClientBehaviorHolder

Tags: jsf, glassfish, cdi, payara

I am trying to shift an application from Windows Server to CentOS 7. This app was not written by me, nor do I have access to the source.

It is running on Payara 6 on Windows at the moment. I picked the WAR file from there. I set up a fresh CentOS 7 VM and am trying to install it there.

So far, I tried installing in both Payara 6 and Glassfish 7. In both cases, I get this error:  CDI deployment failure:javax/faces/component/behavior/ClientBehaviorHolder

Here's the server.log:

```
[2023-02-11T19:56:58.878+0500] [Payara 6.2023.3-SNAPSHOT] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=179 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(9)] [timeMillis: 1676127418878] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:javax/faces/component/behavior/ClientBehaviorHolder -- javax/faces/component/behavior/ClientBehaviorHolder
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.defineLoadedClass(WebappClassLoader.java:3492)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1234)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1806)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1684)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getEnclosingMethod0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.hasEnclosingMethodInfo(Class.java:1794)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.isLocalOrAnonymousClass(Class.java:1790)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.isAnonymousClass(Class.java:1730)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AnnotatedTypeLoader.internalLoadAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeLoader.java:92)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AnnotatedTypeLoader.loadAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeLoader.java:75)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:92)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addLoadedClasses(BeanDeployer.java:199)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createClasses(BeanDeployment.java:197)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startInitialization(WeldStartup.java:409)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:80)
        at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.processApplicationLoaded(WeldDeployer.java:579)
        at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:437)
        at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:344)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:577)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:612)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:552)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:365)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:551)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:582)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:574)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:365)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:573)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1497)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1869)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1755)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:272)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:294)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:136)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:134)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:177)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:478)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:400)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:260)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:239)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:697)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:367)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:335)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:189)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:193)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:193)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
]]
```

I haven't worked with Glassfish before nor do I know what CDI is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a JSF exception - or at least JSF is involved in some way. Better add the relevant tag. Also, does the exception have a root cause?

Comment: No. There is no previous error in the log.